# what is the single query for all comments to all of a specific user's posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given :user has_many :posts which has_many :comments, what is the query to find all the comments to all the user's posts?

`jack = User.find(999)`

Is there a single query to find all the comments to all of Jack's posts?

Comment: Are you asking for all the ***comments of a user*** or all the ***commets to a user_posts***

Comment: all the comments to a user post

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_many :received_comments, through: :posts, class_name: 'Comment' 
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This gives you the ability to query comments through the user

```
jack = User.find(999)
jack.received_comments # all comments made on posts belonging to jack
jack.comments # all comments made by jack
```